# Cannot close Activity while AsyncTask is not finished

Tags: java, android, service, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have an `AsyncTask` running in my `Activity`. In that `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground(Object[])` method I perform a network operation which sends some data to a server using `HTTP POST` method, receives a response, then in its `onPostExecute(Object)` method it sends that response to a `Service` and then all the job is performed from the `Service`. The problem is: I can't close the `Activity` until the `AsyncTask` is finished. The `Activity` just freezes until the `AsyncTask` completes. Sometimes, if the `AsyncTask` needs more time to complete, the screen becomes black and stays like that until the `AsyncTask` is finished. Why is that? How to avoid this? I have tried calling to `AsyncTask`'s `cancel(boolean)` in `Activity`'s `onStop()` method but it still performed the same behaviour.

EDIT: my `AsyncTask` code:

```
private static class PostCommentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Activity activity;
    int status;
    Toast indicationMsg;

    public PostCommentTask(Context context) {
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        Log.i("ilog", "isNetworkAvailable() called");
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected() && activeNetworkInfo.isAvailable();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... param) {
        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            return "";
        }

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(param[7]);
        String responseBody = "error in PostComment.doInBackground()";

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(7);
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somevar", param[0]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somevar", param[1]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somevar", param[2]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somevar", param[3]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somevar", param[4]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somevar", param[5]));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("somevar", param[6]));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.i("ilog", "response status: " + status);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("ilog", "Response: " + responseBody);

        return responseBody;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(String responseBody) {
        String success = "{\"status\":\"OK\"}";
        if (responseBody.equals(success) && status == 200){
            indicationMsg = Toast.makeText(activity, "Success!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            CommentsFragment.CommentsHandler commentsHandler = new CommentsFragment.CommentsHandler();

            Messenger messenger = new Messenger(commentsHandler);

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(activity, WindowService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("messenger", messenger);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("somevar", somevar);
            serviceIntent.putExtra("somevar", activity.getIntent().getStringExtra("somevar"));
            activity.startService(serviceIntent);
            //
        }
        else
            indicationMsg = Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        indicationMsg.show();
    }
}
```

`CommentsHandler` class is a class that handles the response from the `Service`. This is how I made the communication between the `Activity` and the `Service`.

I start the `AsyncTask` with this code:

```
public static class CommentsFragment extends Fragment {
    /** ... **/
    @Override
    public void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** ... **/
        Button queryButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.query_button);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /** ... **/
                new PostCommentTask(activity).execute(somevar, somevar, somevar, somevar, somevar, somevar, somevar, somevar);
                /** ... **/
            }
        });
        /** ...  **/
    }
    /** ... **/
}
```

Comment: there's 99.999% chances you're implementing AsyncTask wrongly. You have to show your code so people can check what is wrong on it.

Comment: As @Budius said this isn't normal. It seems as though you are locking up your thread which is exactly what isn't supposed to happen.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend making the POST request in your service seeing as you have one already. It will make your code much simpler and completely isolate it from the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: I have added my `AsyncTask` class's code in the question above!

Comment: And can you add the code where you start the task as well please?

Comment: I have just added it. Please check it.

Comment: So can someone help me? I really need an answer why my UI Thread is locked when I press the back button before the `AsyncTask` is finished? I can do anything, like pressing other buttons, doing input, scrolling, but when I press the back button the UI Thread freezes until the `AsyncTask` finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue. The `Activity` was freezing because the `Activity` I am going back to from this one is also using `AsyncTask` in its `onResume()` method, so it had to wait until the first task from the closed `Activity` is done before executing its own task and this caused the freeze of the UI. Now I am using `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Object[]` to be able to run multiple tasks parallel, not in series (one by one).